# Checking for alternate keys with XNA IsKeyDown

Tags: xna, c#, input

I'm working on picking up XNA and this was a confusing point for me.

```
KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
{
    //Do stuff...
}
```

The book I'm using (Learning XNA 4.0, O'Rielly) says that this method accepts a bitwise OR series of keys, which I think should look like this...

```
KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left | Keys.A))
{
    //Do stuff...
}
```

But I can't get it work. I also tried using `!IsKeyUp(... | ...)` as it said that all keys had to be down for it to be true, but had no luck with that either. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is it really worth it? Just use an extra keyState.IsKeyDown() with ||

Comment: First of all your two blocks are not equivalent. "keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) && keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A)" for the top would make the blocks logically equivalent. Also could you describe what "But I can't get it work" means? Where is this code. Are threads involved? The second block it should be true iff A and Left are both pressed. Are you not experiencing this behavior?

Comment: I'm only trying to avoid extra code and method calls if I can - this seems like something that should be common with alternate keys in games? I know they're not equivalent, that is why I mentioned the `IsKeyUp` alternative. By "it doesn't work" I meant that I can't ever get it to be true - it doesn't matter if both keys are up, one key is down, or both keys is down. In one of those cases it should be true, but none of them were.

Comment: a better thing to avoid than extra code is confusing code. The second block has confused you and has a higher probability of confusing others so in this case it should be avoided... Even if you get it to work as expected.

Comment: I have this book and just checked the section on Keyboard input. I saw absolutely nothing mentioning bitwise operators. However, there is a section about Gamepad input that claims you can use bitwise to pass multiple Buttons to the IsButtonDown method.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I mixed them up - page 52 has the key methods correctly and page 57 has the gamepad button methods that says you can use bitwise operators. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The XNA [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keys.aspx) struct is not marked with the [Flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) Attribute which means that it's *not* legal to | a load of keys together like that.

```
Keys keyCombo = Keys.Left | Keys.A;
Console.WriteLine(keyCombo);
```

Will print **NumPad5**, which is clearly not what you want here! You've never been able to do this in any version of XNA, I think the book is just wrong here :O

Copying from one of my own games, this is how I solved it:

```
#if WINDOWS
public static bool Any(this KeyboardState state, params Keys[] keys)
{
    return keys.Any(state.IsKeyDown);
}
#endif
```

And then you can just do:

```
KeyboardState k = Keyboard.GetState();

if (k.Any(Keys.Left, Keys.A))
    DoStuff();
```

However, as someone in the comments pointed out **this method is bad practice on the xbox** due to it allocating (params array allocation, and LINQ allocating an Enumerator). An alternative system for xbox is this:

```
Keys[] doStuffKeys; //Allocate an array of keys for this particular action

Initialize()
{
    doStuffKeyBinding = new[] { Keys.Left, Keys.A };
}

Update()
{
    KeyboardState k = Keyboard.GetState();

    if (k.Any(doStuffKeys)) //No allocations here!
        DoStuff();
}
```

The Any method needs modifying too:

```
#if XBOX
public static bool Any(this KeyboardState state, Keys[] keys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
        if (state.IsKeyDown(keys[i]))
            return true;
    return false;
}
#endif
```

It's a while since I've done any work for the xbox, but this now shouldn't allocate.

Comment: Really like the use the extension method here. Thanks! I think that should be `return keys.Any(x => state.IsKeyDown(x));`

Comment: +1 Your method is much more C sharpy. I've been coding Java too long...

Comment: @jocull, I don't need x => state.IsKeyDown(x), the above compiles just fine :)

Comment: You're right, that does compile... but I sort of don't get why. Never written LINQ like that. I guess it is passing the method into `Any(...)` as the `Func<Keys, bool>`?

Comment: +1 For extension methods and LINQ. And @jocull, That's right. It's like how events/delegates can be associated with a lambda expression, anonymous method, or a named method.

Comment: @Jocull, absolutely right. Any takes a Func<Keys, bool> and IsKeyDown *is* a Func<Keys, bool> so all is fine :D

Comment: One minor note, if you are using XNA to develop on the xbox using params and linq will typically generate garbage, which is best avoided. It's not pretty but overloading the method with 1, 2, 3... parameters would get around this.

Comment: Either that, or you preallocate an array of keys. I'll add something to my answer...

Comment: Preallocating would be good I think. If this game example was anything more than a scratch pad I would probably have each key set defined as a static array in an Input class or something and use them sort of like constants. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 4):

`IsKeyDown` takes an enum `Key` for its type. I don't see from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.keyboardstate.iskeydown.aspx) that it can take multiple emums ORed together. Perhaps your book is wrong?

You could create your own method if you wanted the shortcut:

```
boolean anyOfTheseDown(KeyboardState keyState, params Keys[] keys) {
   boolean result = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
   {
       result |= keyState.IsKeyDown(keys[i]);
   }    
   return result;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
if (anyOfTheseDown(keyState, Keys.Left, Keys.A))
{
    //Do stuff...
}
```

Code is untested.

Comment: I like this solution if bitwise is out of the question. Is the for loop considered unnecessary overhead? Would it be better to just write it twice with a traditional `||`? Not trying to micro-optimize and scrutinize this too much, but genuinely curious about writing the best code I can.

Comment: It depends, the method above will allow 1 or more keys to be checked. The for loop will not add any (noticeable) additional overhead for checking multiple key states. But you do appear to be pre-micro-optimizing :) If you worry this much about this level of detail, you'll never finish.

Comment: @joculi For your case this seems the most convenient, doesn't it? Using enum flags would be more useful in checking for a group of keys being pressed exclusively, but making sure that each frame you build an "isDown" enum value of the keys that are down this frame to bitwise-compare to the requested key combination. But even that's still prematurely optimizing.