# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class when adding static bool function

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I try to use first answer of [Checking for alternate keys with XNA IsKeyDown](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37631/checking-for-alternate-keys-with-xna-iskeydown) but the compiler shows me Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is great for answering these kinds of language questions.

Comment: Developer pro-tip, Google the error code first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10412233/extension-method-must-be-defined-in-non-generic-static-class

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed by the given answer (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/37637/18568) uses the C# language concept of Extension Methods. These are described in more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). What you are doing is effectively 'tacking on' another method to a pre-made class definition that you are unable to modify directly, due to it being supplied as part of a library, or in another form or situation such that the original class should not be edited directly.

To answer your question simply, the snippet of the `Any` method supplied in the post you linked above is incomplete. By requirement of the C# language, an Extension Method (identified by the use of `this` as a prefix of the first parameter) must be within a static class. The class type of the method parameter prefixed by `this` is the class to which the extension method applies; it essentially forces the method to be a member of  that class, with the only difference being that the `this` keyword does not work within the method as it would for a traditional non-static method, and you must instead use the name of the `this`-prefixed parameter.

```
#if WINDOWS
namespace MyKeyboardExtensions
{
    public static class MyKeyboardStateExtensionClass
    {
        public static bool Any(this KeyboardState state, params Keys[] keys)
        {
            return keys.Any(state.IsKeyDown);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Following this, you need to make sure that you specify `using MyKeyboardExtensions;` wherever you want the extension method(s) to take effect. Keep in mind, also, that extension methods cannot access private variables of the extended class, since otherwise they'd just rip a hole in some pretty basic OOP principles.